# How to edit the files of wordpress.org hosted site if wp-admin is not works?

Tags: wordpress

My site is hosted on the wordpress.org. I don't have the access for files. As you already know wordpress.org hosted sites not provides the file access. But i want to edit the files for client requirements. So for that i installed the File manager plugin.

I have updated the files that have small syntax error by mistake. So site stopped working. Now please suggest anything how i update the file again because everything has stopped.

Please suggest how would i recover my site again?

Comment: Tried contacting WordPress support?

Comment: I don't have the login details for wordpress.org. And i didn't find anything on support forum.

Comment: I am a developer.  I am not owner of this site. I am working on this site. I have only wp-admin details but back end is not working right now.